# ExtJS Gridpanel

Tags: extjs

I want to dispaly 'Report' hyperlink on Gridpanel paging toolbar (or Title bar)
how can i do it (click on Report link display window with grid data)
Plz help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about something very simple like this. (The default object for `Toolbar`'s `add` method is `Button`. Have a look at [ExtJS API documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Button) if you want something more fancy.)

```
gridPanel.getTopToolbar().add({
    text:'<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Visit Stackoverflow.com</a>'
});
```

Comment: ThanQ for ur replay but iam not getting(i wnat to dislay link button alnog with display message on paging control)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is. The above code should add a new button to your toolbar. You can place any text you want inside the `text` config option, HTML markup is allowed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a link in the ExtJS GridPanel Titlebar.

I will be creating  a button in tools config of the gridpanel, and set its ui config to plain,
also you can write the handler according to your requirements.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    title: 'Demo Grid Panel'
    tools: [
               { ui: 'plain',text: 'Open Window', handler : function(){ //link handler}}
           ]
});
```